# Add a php created array into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a javascript slide show on my index page. Instead of the array being static, I want to build the array with PHP and add it with something like and include  statement. Since the array is inside the javascript I am unsure how best to do this. Here is a sample of the array:

```
var fadeimages=new Array()
    fadeimages[0]=["pics/fade_pic_1.jpg", "", ""]
    fadeimages[1]=["pics/fade_pic_2.jpg", "", ""]
    fadeimages[2]=["pics/fade_pic_3.jpg", "", ""]
```

And here is the PHP file that builds the array. It works great. I just don't know how to place it in the javascript code:

```
<?php // Build fadepic array for index page
$x=0;
foreach (glob("pics/*.*") as $filename) {
$filename = substr($filename, 20); //gets just the file name
echo "fadeimages[".$x."]=[\"pics/".$filename."\", \"\", \"\"]<br>";
$x++;
}  ?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: Convert the PHP version to _JSON_

Comment: You could build the PHP array as normal, then put it into javascript with `var fadeimages = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?> ;`

Comment: If you will place result into `eval()` function you will have your array, however it is quite unclean way to do this. Better use JSON as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) for this.

```
<?php
//buildfadepic.php
$result = array();
foreach (glob("pics/*.*") as $filename) {
    $result[] = array("pics/".$filename, "", "");
}
print json_encode($result);
```

This will give you valid JSON (and hence valid JavaScript). If you want to mix JavaScript and PHP, you should be able to do it like this now

```
var fadeimages = <?php include "buidfadepic.php"; ?>;
```

Since buidfadepic.php will give you a result like this

```
[ ["pics/foo.jpg", "", ""], ["pics/bar.png", "", ""], ...]
```

Or if you have both in the same file, simply print/echo instead of include as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Even better way would be -return- the $result, and to the json_encode from the view, because the buildfadepic.php should do only the building IMHO

Comment: I can't get this to work. the area where the images should be is blank.

Answer (score 0):

The right way, as the comments said would be using `json_encode`.
For example:

Server

```
<?php
$files = array('file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.jpg');
$view->assing_var('files', $files); // if you're separating the view from the php, else just do return for including
```

View (client):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = <?=json_encode($files)?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other posters that JSON would be a nice clean way to do this. But you don't necessarily *have* to, you can also include the array straight away:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fadeimages=new Array();
  <?php 
    echo "fadeimages[0] = ...;"; // Include code to create array
  ?>
</script>
```

Just to clarify (based on the comments we seem to have a bit of misunderstanding): you *can* put PHP code *inside* `<script>` tags. After all, the PHP code is run server-side and the client that runs the JavaScript will also see the resulting output. So as long as your PHP script does not produce syntax errors in the JavaScript you should be OK.

An alternative approach, if the script becomes very large, is to include your PHP script as an external JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="list_fade_images.php"></script>
```

Comment: @user3301501, that is not obvious to me. Please explain why not?

Comment: You can not embed php code directly into javascript as in your example.

Comment: Yes, that is what you said, and I asked you why but you still have not given me a reason. I just ran this code: http://pastebin.com/0UD5aAij and it worked as I expected, so either I am misunderstanding your question or you are misunderstanding my answer.